# Using AJAX and PHP to load next post object

Tags: posts, ajax

After looking through the jQuery documentation and many stackexchange community forums, I am still faced with this problem.  Taking little bits from here and there have helped me get this far, but I am stuck where I am now.

Im using an ajax request to try and load the next post after the one that is currently displayed.  The only issue I run into is when I try to execute the method included in my php file:

```
<?php

echo getnext();

function getnext(){


$post = get_post($_POST['id']);

$prevPost = get_previous_post();

return $prevPost->post_content;



}
?>
```

I can echo the POST variable that is being passed in fine, but once I try to actually call the method I get a 500 internal Server Error.

My AJAX request looks like this:

```
      setTimeout(function (){

$currid = $('#post_id').val();

$.post("wp-content/themes/stargazer/populate.php",
            {
                "id":$currid
            },
            function(data){
                //$("#academiccontent").html(data);
                alert (data);
            });

$('#academiccontent').animate({ 'opacity': 1 });

 }, 1000);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Ive been stuck on this for a long while now.

Thanks!!

Comment: There are a lot of questions here regarding the use of AJAX in WordPress, I suggest starting there, as well as reading about [AJAX in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are trying to pass to cannot be used (wp-content/themes/stargazer/populate.php)

As @Milo pointed out, please check the [AJAX Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), and it will explain the use of 'ajaxurl', which is a protected variable.

In short, all AJAX requests must be passed through 'admin-ajax.php' whether it is for the frontend or backend.